# Custom media(picture and video) using photo_manager package in flutter not working

Tags: flutter, compiler-errors, package, photo-gallery

I'm working on a flutter app where i want to build a custom gallery to show my pictures and videos. I'm trying to use the photo_manager package to achieve this,however whenever i add the package to my pubspec.yaml and run my app  I get the error below  without even using the package.

```
e: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin\java" (in directory "C:\Users\Sylvester\AppData\Local\kotlin\daemon"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':photo_manager:compileDebugKotlin'.
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin\java": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 57s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Please any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I ran these commands and it seemed to fix it

```
flutter clean
flutter pub upgrade
flutter pub get
```